# What does "SELECT /*!N SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mytable`" mean in in MySQL's slow query log?

Tags: mysql

I've just turned on [slow query logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) on my MySQL database, adding the following to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
```

When I run [mysqldumpslow](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldumpslow.html), it outputs the following:

```
Reading mysql slow query log from mysql-slow.log
Count: 1  Time=199.23s (199s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=32513.0 (32513), ...
 SELECT /*!N SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mytable`

...
```

Looking at the original `mysql-slow.log`, the full query was:

```
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `mytable`;
```

So `mysqldumpslow` just replaced the number with `N` (to assist aggregating similar queries.)

So, the question is, where does that query come from and what does the `/*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */` bit mean?

As best I can tell, it's probably from a `mysqldump` command that was doing a backup (hence not wanting cached data), does that seem right? And if so, since it only read 32,000 rows, why did it take 199s?

There are a bunch more similar queries on other tables taking 100s, 50s, down to a more reasonable 3s, most having about 10-20,000 rows, the biggest with 450,000 rows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The query is probably 'slow' because the client (your backup system) is having to read every row in your table; which is taking apparently 199 seconds.

Note that if you did something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 100;

// read 50 rows

// sleep for 5 minutes

// read last 50 rows
```

The above query would appear in the slow log, because from when it first started, to when it could finish (by sending you the last requested row) it took 5 minutes.

Comment: But the "backup system" is mysqldump, surely that doesn't take 200 seconds to write 32,000 rows?

Comment: Actually, if it's sending that over ssh (via gzip) that could be keeping it open until the data is all transferred...

Comment: Do a SHOW PROCESSLIST when the query is running, if its status is 'writing to net' (I think) then its sending the data as fast as your other end is processing it.

Comment: doing the mysqldump to a local file takes a second or two, so it was definitely the gzip/ssh that slowed it down and made the queries appear in the slow query log. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 34):

The `/*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */` means that in versions of mysql >= 4.0.1 execute `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM mytable` and in earlier versions execute the command without the SQL_NO_CACHE.

Also mysqldump does use the `/*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */` syntax.

I'm not sure why your queries would be so slow.

Comment: Ah, a version number! I thought it may have been an error code or something. That's good to know, is there any documentation for that syntax?

Comment: Yeah you can find some information on the MySQL site at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html

Comment: This should be the correct answer. I don't suppose the main question was: "Why are my queries slow?" At least not in the title

Answer (score 5):

A matter of tuning may be considered by you to make this query run faster than it, btw, SQL_NO_CACHE means that this query will run without be eligible to be stored into query cache. For example, you can use this HINT, SQL_NO_CACHE, to avoid this query to be cached so as to test that execution time.

Check it out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html

More HINTS to use into queries: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/613.cfm

Cheers, WB

Comment: The first page has moved and does not seem to be that useful anymore:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/statement-caching.html
The second page had the info I needed!

Answer (score -1):

From My Work, I also faced the same issue Then I tried in two ways to solve it.

Firstly, I have increase the `mysql_query_cache` size and increase the space in local Machine.

Secondly, I have checked the remote server `mysql_query_cache` size and increase the temp directory space.

Because, What I got from research that this system is working in both ways and giving us sense that we have to increase the space in the specific place.

So, Be specific which `mysqldum`p you are using and check out the version also for both system. As different version also behave slight different.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the asked question?

Comment: I got the same error and I solved this by those step. I mean it is not related to slow query log. It is about the space size in the system. That's how the answer is related to the question.

Comment: But this question isn't about an error, but asking for an explanation about what something means?